# How Can I break in my stored procedure code that is under Test in SSMS

Tags: ssms, tsqlt

I am using tSQLt to test my sql stored procedures. I would like to be able to debug my stored procedure within the contexts of the test (with the faked tables etc).

I'm having issues setting/hitting a breakpoint in SSMS while debugging.

The code I'm starting the debugger in looks something like:

```
EXEC tSQLt.run  @TestName = '[someTestClass].[test something]'
```

I am able to step into this call and various subsequent calls but this is very annoying. I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint in my stored procedure under test but I cannot find any documentation on how to accomplish this besides [this](https://sqlserverfunctions.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/setting-breakpoints-in-ssms/) which seems to be outdated for SSMS 2017.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint in a stored proc using the object explorer in SSMS? Is there a method in TSQLT that makes it easier to step into a test/code under test? Is there a better tool for debugging something like this other than SSMS?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not using breakpoints in SSMS. However the way I'm debugging tests is, I'm expanding the source code of the procedure and wrap it to the BEGIN TRANSACTION...ROLLBACK and then use SELECT/PRINT statements inside

Answer (score 1):

This is how I debug my tests, I came onto this question looking for best practices/how other people debug their tests so hopefully someone can provide a better answer.

My object code is stored in DB projects/deployed via dacpacs. When developing the tests I deploy the DB from visual studio, then execute `tsqlt.Run` via SSMS.

In my tsqlt databases I have a custom table

```
CREATE TABLE [tSQLt].[DebugTests]
(
    [IsDebug] bit not null default 1,
    constraint PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY ([IsDebug]),
     constraint CK_T1_Locked CHECK ([IsDebug]=1)
)
```

If I am actively debugging my tests, I insert into that table and my tests will know that they are in Debug mode and should print/return stuff.

```
INSERT INTO tSQLt.DebugTests(IsDebug)
VALUES(1);
```

Inside of my tests, I include this snippet at the beginning of the sproc. This sets a variable that I can then use throughout the sproc to surface various info as I need.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [tests_schema].[test myStuff]
AS
DECLARE @Debug BIT=
     (
         SELECT CASE
                    WHEN COALESCE(IsDebug, 0) = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
         FROM tSQLt.DebugTests
     );

#For instance, I might want to see what my fake table looks like
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable '[dbo].[MyTable]';

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([Column1],[column5])
Values
(1,'Value')
,(2,'AnotherValue')

if (@Debug = 1)
     select 'FakeDataArrange' as [ResultType],'[dbo].[MyTable]' 'TableName', * from [dbo].[MyTable]

#I might also want to see what the actual results of my stored proc/view are. Or surface the #Expected values so that I do not have to jump back to the source code to remember what this test is expecting.
IF(@Debug = 1)
         SELECT '#Actual' 'ResultType', *
         FROM #Actual;
```

Then truncate the `[tSQLt].[DebugTests]` when you are done. This is not performant if you spit out all of these debug messages/results every time, so you really want to make sure that you only have a value in that table when you are actively developing tests.

I have found this to be pretty good for my workflow. Normally I only need to see the values of my faked tables to be able to figure out what is wrong. That being said, I am not testing any complex code, just basic stored procs that are used for reports.